# Can I integrate Chromedriver into a Maven Project where I don't need put it in my local machine?

Tags: maven, automation, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber-serenity

What I am doing now is I am putting my Chromedriver in my local machine C://Program Files/chromedriver. Is there a way to integrate/put chromedriver in my Java Maven Project for Automation testing using serenity cucumber so I don't have to manually put to my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, look for `webdrivermanager` in maven from bonigarcia;

And instead of setting the path to the driver, just do:

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
```

This will download the appropriate driver and set the path to the driver.